# Kurento RecorderEndpoint is not storing to remote network storage

Tags: video-recording, kurento

Kurento recording endpoint
https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_static/client-javadoc/org/kurento/client/RecorderEndpoint.html

As per the documentation it supports storing the recording on remote network storage. I am trying to store a recording on Azure blob storage. The storage supports chunked encoding mode as expected by the endpoint.

Recording works fine when I use local file system. There is nothing uploaded on Azure container when I use Azure URI (in the form http(s)://username:password@host:port/path/to/file).

Is there any sample code available for storing to remote location. Any guidance would be appreciated.